# Column order of `.SD` in j argument differs when `get()` is used

Tags: r, data.table

I very often transform subsets of data using the `.SDcols` option in `data.table`. <strike>It makes sense that the `.SD` columns sent to `j` are in the same order as the original data.table</strike>.

**EDITED to properly identify the issue**

It's nice that `.SD` columns have the same order as that specified in the `.SDcols` argument.  This **does not** happen when `get` is used in the `j` argument (inside an `lapply` call, at least).  In this case, the `.SD` table columns maintain their original order.

Is there any way to override this behaviour?

## An example without `get` works fine

```
# library(data.table)
dt = data.table(col1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 4), 
            b = rnorm(12),
            a = 1:12,
            c = LETTERS[1:12])

# columns I want to do something to
d.vars = c('a', 'b')  #' names in different order than names(dt)


# Generate columns of first differences by group
dt[, paste('d', d.vars, sep='.') := 
    lapply(.SD, function(L) L  - shift(L, n = 1, type='lag') ), 
      keyby = col1, .SDcols = d.vars]
```

<strike>The result is assigns differenced values to the "wrong" column because my named vector (`d.vars`) is ordered differently than the columns in `dt`.  The result is:</strike>

The results are as expected, the `.SD` table's columns are ordered the same way as the names in `d.vars`.

```
> dt
   col1           b  a c d.a         d.b
1:    A -0.28901751  1 A  NA          NA
2:    A  0.65746901  4 D   3  0.94648651
3:    A -0.10602462  7 G   3 -0.76349362
4:    A -0.38406252 10 J   3 -0.27803790
5:    B -1.06963450  2 B  NA          NA
6:    B  0.35137273  5 E   3  1.42100723
7:    B  0.43394046  8 H   3  0.08256772
8:    B  0.82525042 11 K   3  0.39130996
9:    C  0.50421710  3 C  NA          NA
10:   C -1.09493665  6 F   3 -1.59915375
11:   C -0.04858163  9 I   3  1.04635501
12:   C  0.45867279 12 L   3  0.50725443
```

Which is the expected output because `lapply` in `j` processed column `a` first and `b` second, in spite of the column order in `dt`.

## Example with `get` behaves differently

```
dt2 = data.table(col1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 4),
            b = rnorm(12),
            a = 1:12,
            neg = -1,
            c = LETTERS[1:12])

# columns I want to do something to
d.vars = c('a', 'b')  #' names in different order than names(dt)

# name of variable to be called in j.
negate <- 'neg'

dt2[, paste('d', d.vars, sep='.') :=
    lapply(.SD, function(L)  {(L  - shift(L, n = 1, type='lag') ) * get(negate) }),
       keyby = col1, .SDcols = d.vars]
```

Now the naming of the newly created columns doesn't align with the name order in `d.vars`:

```
 > dt2
    col1          b  a neg c         d.a d.b
 1:    A -0.3539066  1  -1 A          NA  NA
 2:    A  0.2702374  4  -1 D -0.62414408  -3
 3:    A -0.7834941  7  -1 G  1.05373150  -3
 4:    A -1.2765652 10  -1 J  0.49307118  -3
 5:    B -0.2936422  2  -1 B          NA  NA
 6:    B -0.2451996  5  -1 E -0.04844252  -3
 7:    B -1.6577614  8  -1 H  1.41256181  -3
 8:    B  1.0668059 11  -1 K -2.72456737  -3
 9:    C -0.1160938  3  -1 C          NA  NA
10:    C -0.7940771  6  -1 F  0.67798333  -3
11:    C  0.2951743  9  -1 I -1.08925140  -3
12:    C -0.4508854 12  -1 L  0.74605969  -3
```

In this second example the `b` column is processed by `lapply` first and therefore assigned to `d.a`.

If I refer to `neg` directly (i.e., I don't use `get`) then the results are as expected: `lapply` processes the `.SD` columns in the order given in `d.vars`.

---

p.s. Thanks data.table team! I love this package!

Comment: god. you're right... clearly I wasn't paying close attention when making this example.  I was getting the "wrong" assignments as described when working with my full dataset.... but the issue must lie somewhere else

Comment: I think what you meant is the order of the columns i.e. d.b should be before d.a.  I updated the answer.

Comment: I editted the question to reflect the fact that the column order of `.SD` is **normally** the order of the named vector in `.SDcols`, but it takes the order of the original `data.table` when `get()` is called in `lapply`. thnx

Comment: Even though you're happy with the answer below, if I understand correctly this sounds like a bug that the devs might appreciate a report on: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support for instructions. A simpler illustration is `dt2[, {get(negate); names(.SD)}, .SDcols=d.vars]` could be related to this other issue, maybe: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1744

Comment: @Frank - it seemed like a bug.  I posted it: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2036

Comment: Ok cool. Fyi, the Support page I linked to says you should test on the development version before reporting (but you indicate you used 1.9.8). https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description, we can use `match` to match the 'd.vars' and the column names of 'dt' ('d.vars1') and then use it to get the order right

```
d.vars1 <- d.vars[match(names(dt), d.vars, nomatch = 0)]
dt[, paste0("d.",d.vars1) := lapply(.SD, function(L)
        L  - shift(L, n = 1, type='lag') ), keyby = col1, .SDcols = d.vars1]
dt
#    col1           b  a c         d.b d.a
# 1:    A -0.28901751  1 A          NA  NA
# 2:    A  0.65746901  4 D  0.94648652   3
# 3:    A -0.10602462  7 G -0.76349363   3
# 4:    A -0.38406252 10 J -0.27803790   3
# 5:    B -1.06963450  2 B          NA  NA
# 6:    B  0.35137273  5 E  1.42100723   3
# 7:    B  0.43394046  8 H  0.08256773   3
# 8:    B  0.82525042 11 K  0.39130996   3
# 9:    C  0.50421710  3 C          NA  NA
#10:    C -1.09493665  6 F -1.59915375   3
#11:    C -0.04858163  9 I  1.04635502   3
#12:    C  0.45867279 12 L  0.50725442   3
```

#### Update

Based on the new dataset

```
d.vars1 <- d.vars[match(names(dt2), d.vars, nomatch = 0)]
dt2[, paste0('d.', d.vars1) := lapply(.SD, function(L) 
    L  - shift(L, n = 1, type='lag') * get(negate) ), 
            keyby = col1, .SDcols = d.vars1]
dt2
#    col1          b  a neg c        d.b d.a
# 1:    A -0.3539066  1  -1 A         NA  NA
# 2:    A  0.2702374  4  -1 D -0.0836692   5
# 3:    A -0.7834941  7  -1 G -0.5132567  11
# 4:    A -1.2765652 10  -1 J -2.0600593  17
# 5:    B -0.2936422  2  -1 B         NA  NA
# 6:    B -0.2451996  5  -1 E -0.5388418   7
# 7:    B -1.6577614  8  -1 H -1.9029610  13
# 8:    B  1.0668059 11  -1 K -0.5909555  19
# 9:    C -0.1160938  3  -1 C         NA  NA
#10:    C -0.7940771  6  -1 F -0.9101709   9
#11:    C  0.2951743  9  -1 I -0.4989028  15
#12:    C -0.4508854 12  -1 L -0.1557111  21
```

Comment: That certainly works for this example because we know `d.vars` are the reverse order of columns in `dt`.  I was hoping for something more general... perhaps something like `d.vars[sapply(d.vars, function(x) grep(x,names(dt)]`... but this won't work if the names in `d.vars` are subsets of one another.

Comment: @TonyBeans I updated the post.  Not sure if this is what you meant

Comment: thanks - this workaround is helpful for my current issue.  I updated by question after you noticed that my example performed the way I wanted/expected.  The problem is not `.SD` itself, but the changed behaviour when `get()` is used, or so it seems.

Comment: @TonyBeans I am not getting the problem when i use `d.vars1`